# Matching LED intensity

Tags: led

I am trying to measure the power output of different color LED at different distances. I used 3 PWM to control a RGB LED, but the power output of the Blue LED was significantly higher than the others. The thing is it seems the blue LED is adjusted to match human eye preception. How do I match the intensity output of the different colour LEDs?

Comment: How? Has your measurement device got a flat spectral response over the visible light spectrum?

Comment: The power output of an LED is set by the circuit you put it in, so unless this is an LED module with an internal power supply preset to some value, the blue LED intensity will be whatever you are driving it at.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt the LEDs in a RGB LED package would be matched for human eye perception.

They are just three separate LED chips in same package and it is the job of the user of that LED package as a whole to use the individual LEDs as suited for some purpose.

Different LEDs have different efficiencies and different forward voltage drops, so you need to adjust the PWM duty or the used current accordingly, maybe by tuning the current limiting resistors or some constant current supplies.

If you want to match intensities, turn all the LEDs on and if the colour is not white then reduce the brightest LED and second brightest LED until you have only one LED at 100% and the light is white.